# Casting Generics

Tags: c#, generics

Can I cast

```
IInterface<MyClass>
```

to

```
IInterface<IAnother>
```

when MyClass implements IAnother?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What specific problem are you attempting to address?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Covariance and contravariance real world example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662369/covariance-and-contravariance-real-world-example)

Comment: I'm not familiar with C#, but you can in Java.
Should just be something like:
`(IInterface<IAnother>)myInstanceOfIInterfaceWithMyClass;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but only if your're using C# 4 (or beyond) and, `IInterface` is declared as `IInterface<out T>`.

This is called generic covariance, you can find more information on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx), or this (more formal but more understandable) [introduction](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2009/04/13/c-4-0-feature-focus-part-4-generic-co-and-contra-variance-for-delegate-and-interface-types.aspx) from Bart de Smet.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in [C# 4 via Covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx), provided you decorate your usage scenario correctly (ie: `IInterface<out IAnother>`).

Note that there are potential side effects to doing this, depending on your interface usage.  I recommend reading up on [Variance in Generic Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059.aspx) for more details, but the main issue is that it's possible to get yourself into a situation where you can have runtime errors because you're giving up some type safety.

Answer (score 1):

look at covariance and contravariance in C# 4.0