# Recasting to base class in C#

Tags: c#, class, casting, derived-class, base-class

In the following C# setup a class A derived from class X and some method getting a list of List as parameter,

```
class X 
{...};

class A : X
{...};

List<A> listA;
List<X> listX;

void SomeMethod(ref List<X>)
{...};
```

is there any way to use that same method for class A (which was derived from X)? Recasting that list from A to X seems to not work.

```
SomeMethod(ref listX); // Works
SomeMethod(ref (List<X>)listA); // Does not work
```

Comment: As a minor note, to you or to readers, make sure you really understand what ref does in C#: it's not the same as in C++, and often confuses new resharpers, and they end up using it when they don't really need to.  Here's a great article providing an explanation of argument passing in C#: http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: Yes, the ref is of course not necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it will already work because `IEnumerable` is **covariant** on its generic type parameter.

If you modify your signature like this:

```
void SomeMethod(ref IEnumerable<X>)
{...};
```

Then you can pass a `List<X>` *or* a `List<A>` to it and be just fine.

As a total aside, its very weird that you are passing that by `ref`. You usually don't pass reference types that way.

Comment: For a great discussion on covariance, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662369/covariance-and-contravariance-real-world-example

Comment: Yes, sure sorry for the ref. I missed that.

Answer (score 3):

Two possibilities.

One, redefine `void SomeMethod(List<X> list)` as `void SomeMethod(IEnumerable<X> list)`.

Because the `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant, you can pass an `IEnumerable<A>` as to a method with an `IEnumerable<X>` parameter, and it will work.

Two, redefine `void SomeMethod(List<X> list)` as `void SomeMethod<T>(List<T> list) where T : X`.

Here you have a generic `SomeMethod` that will work with lists of any type derived from `X`, including `X` itself.

(Even better if you can is to define the method as `void SomeMethod<T>(List<T> list)` [without the `where`] or better still, as `SomeMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)` as then you've a method applicable to even more cases than those you are currently thinking about, but I'm going to assume you need to make use of some features of `X` and those therefore aren't viable).

Note also that as people have said the `ref` is unusual here (I just took it out in the above), and it also causes further problems. To use `ref` you need an assignable variable (a local variable, a parameter, a settable property or an array access) of the appropriate type, as `ref` needs to be able to assign as well as access. Hence you can never cast when passing to a `ref` variable as `SomeMethod(ref (List<X>)listA)` attempts to do, even if `listA` could be cast to `List<X>` (which it can't anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for answering not to your direct question. I'd recommend you to get rid of List<A> and use List<X> both places. Create instances of A and add them to List<X>.

Now according to your direct question. It's possible as @BradleyDotNet answered. See this URL for more details and examples: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Umm... that suggestion didn't make much sense. Thanks for the shout out though!