# C# generic classes inheritance compile time error

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following code:

```
public class EntitySchema
{
}

public class ContactEntitySchema : EntitySchema
{
}

public class ProductEntitySchema : EntitySchema
{
}

public class Entity<TEntitySchema>
    where TEntitySchema : EntitySchema
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class Contact : Entity<ContactEntitySchema>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Product : Entity<ProductEntitySchema>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ViewBase<TEntity>
    where TEntity : Entity<EntitySchema>
{
    public TEntity Entity { get; set; }
}

public class ContactView : ViewBase<Contact>
{
    public ContactView()
    {
    }
}

public class ProductView : ViewBase<Entity<EntitySchema>>
{
    public ProductView()
    {
    }
}
```

I get the following error for ContactView class:

> Error  1   The type `'Generics.Contact'` cannot be used as type parameter `'TEntity'` in the generic type or method `'Generics.ViewBase<TEntity>'`. There is no implicit reference conversion from `'Generics.Contact'` to `'Generics.Entity<Generics.EntitySchema>'`.

Then I define ProductView a bit different and it compiles successfully. However, in ProductView I should explicitly cast the Entity property to Product if I want to use some of the Product specific fields. Is there a way to rework the declaration of ContactView so I can specify the actual Entity type (in this particular case - Contact)?

Comment: I think this is a problem of covariance/contravariance, take a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662369/covariance-and-contravariance-real-world-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is that `public class Entity<TEntitySchema>` is [generically invariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That means that even though *you* know that `ContactEntitySchema : EntitySchema` that doesn't mean the compiler can substitute `ContactEntitySchema` for `EntitySchema` in the generic type definition for `ViewBase`.

(To understand why that's the case, consider what happens if you try to treat a `List<Cat>` as if it were a `List<Animal>`, or vice-versa.)

I might have misunderstood your problem, but to start with you could try specifying the schema type directly in the type parameters for your view, using a type constraint to make sure the relationship between `TEntity` and `TSchema` is preserved?:-

```
public class ViewBase<TEntity, TSchema>
    where TEntity : Entity<TSchema>
    where TSchema : EntitySchema
{
    public TEntity Entity { get; set; }
}

public class ContactView : ViewBase<Contact, ContactEntitySchema>
{
    public ContactView()
    {
    }
}

public class ProductView : ViewBase<Entity<EntitySchema>, EntitySchema>
{
    public ProductView()
    {
    }
}
```

Alternately, you can change `Entity` into an interface:-

```
public interface IEntity<out TEntitySchema>
    where TEntitySchema : EntitySchema
{
    string Id { get; set; }
}

public class Contact : IEntity<ContactEntitySchema>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
// etc
```

which allows you to specify that the `TEntitySchema` generic type parameter is covariant (using the `out` keyword).

Either solution should allow you to access `this.TEntity` in a strongly-typed fashion in your view objects.

Comment: Thank you very much! I reworked the code as you suggested and now everything works fine! :)