# C# Generics Casting. Casting from Base Class

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have a C# viewmodel to which I'm passing a generic type in the constructor:

```
public ViewModelTestPage(IIncrementalLoadingHelper<MessageDTO> incrementalLoadingHelper)
    {
        IncrementalLoadingHelper = incrementalLoadingHelper;
    }
```

In my `ViewModel` base class I have the following property:

```
public IIncrementalLoadingHelper<BaseDTO> IncrementalLoadingHelper {get; set;}
```

`MessageDTO` inherits from `BaseDTO`.

On the line which sets `IncrementalLoadingHelper = incrementalLoadingHelper`, I'm getting an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `IIncrementalLoadingHelper<MessageDTO>` to `IIncrementalLoadingHelper<BaseDTO>`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I probably am missing a cast, but I have no idea how to do this.  Could someone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: The formatting messed up the real error:- Cannot implicitly convert type 'IIncrementalLoadingHelper<MessageDTO>' to 'IIncrementalLoadingHelper<BaseDTO>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Covariance and contravariance real world example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662369/covariance-and-contravariance-real-world-example)

Comment: Does MessageDTO descend from BaseDTO? What does the definition of IncrementalLoadingHelper look like?

Answer (score 0):

All you actually need is a [generic `out` modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) on the generic type:

```
    class BaseDTO { }
    class MessageDTO : BaseDTO { }
    interface IIncrementalLoadingHelper<out T> { }

    class ViewModelTestPage
    {
        IIncrementalLoadingHelper<BaseDTO> IncrementalLoadingHelper { get; }

        public ViewModelTestPage(IIncrementalLoadingHelper<MessageDTO> incrementalLoadingHelper)
        {
            IncrementalLoadingHelper = incrementalLoadingHelper;
        }
    }
```

That said, it doesn't make much sense to me that the property is of the base type, but the constructor takes the derived type. Why not just use the derived type as the property type then?