# use a dictionary with an interface as value for method parameter

Tags: c#

Why isn't it possible to pass

```
Dictionary<string, PinkLady>()
```

into my `Supply(Dictionary<string, IApple> apples)` method?

```
public interface IApple { }

public class PinkLady : IApple { }

public void Supply(Dictionary<string, IApple> apples) { }

public void TestMethod()
{
    //Working
    Supply(new Dictionary<string, IApple>());

    //Not working
    Supply(new Dictionary<string, PinkLady>());
}
```

I always get an error:

> converting from Dictionary into Dictionary not possible. PinkLady does not match expected type IApple.

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662369/covariance-and-contravariance-real-world-example

Comment: You're asking it to guarantee that an instance of `Dictionary<string, PinkLady>` can safely be treated as `Dictionary<string, IApple>` in all cases. But `Dictionary<string, IApple>` guarantees that you can call `Add(myCortland)` on it, and `Dictionary<string, PinkLady>` guarantees that you can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the types `Dictionary<string, IApple>` and `Dictionary<string, PinkyLady>` are not the same types. `PinkyLady` might derive from `IApple` but this is in the context of `Dictionary` being generic. They compile into two different types.

What you can do to solve it is make `Support` a generic method with a constraint:

```
public void Supply<T>(Dictionary<string, T> apples) where T : IApple { /* ... */ }
```