# Pass a List of a class into method with list of an abstract base class as a parameter (Covariance)

Tags: c#, covariance

I have classes that inherit from an abstract base class, and I want to pass a `List` of any of those classes into a method that that has a `List` of the base class as a parameter. How can I make that happen?

Here is want I've tried -

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass {}

public class MyClass1 : MyBaseClass {}

//Inside another class
public void MyMethod(List<MyBaseClass> listOfBaseClass){}

//Inside another class
List<MyClass1> myClass1List = new List<MyClass1>();
MyMethod(myClass1List); //ERROR HERE, This method call does not compile
```

Is there anyway to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Try it with IEnumerable<MyBaseClass> as the argument type

Comment: [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) uses the [out generic modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier), which List or IList does not.
Thats why IEnumerable works here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to pass collections of derived types of `MyBaseClass`, you'll need to change the signature

```
public void MyMethod(List<MyBaseClass> listOfBaseClass){}
```

To a type which supports covariance, such as `IEnumerable` or `IReadOnlyCollection`, e.g.:

```
public void MyMethod(IEnumerable<MyBaseClass> listOfBaseClass){}
```

This is because `List` is invariant, whereas `IEnumerable` is covariant. The reason why the compiler is strict is because `List` allows for change to the collection, e.g. if `MyMethod` would be allowed to do this:

```
public void MyMethod(List<MyBaseClass> listOfBaseClass)
{
    listOfBaseClass.Add(new AnotherClass());
}
```

Where `AnotherClass` was another subclass of `MyBaseClass`, it would `break` the caller's collection which was supposed to be of `List<MyClass1>()`;.

More about [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42660356/314291)

Answer (score 1):

Declare your method with a parameter of type `IReadOnlyList<T>`.

You cannot receive `List<T>` or `IList<T>` because they are not read-only. If you could pass a `List<MyClass1>` argument into a method as a `IList<MyBaseClass>` parameter, the method could attempt to add a `MyClass2` object into the list (assuming `MyClass2` is another inheritor of `MyBaseClass`). It would be OK from the method's perspective, but it would cause runtime failure - so the C# language prevents it right off.

Your problem will be solved if you would use a read-only list. For example, a parameter of type `IReadOnlyList<MyBaseClass>` would accept argument of type `List<MyClass1>` - because `List<T>` implements `IReadOnlyList<T>`, and `IReadOnlyList<T>` declares `T` as `out`.

In this way you don't have to resort to `IEnumerable<T>`, and won't lose count and random access by index.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the signature to be generic, and then constrain the generic type to be a subclass of your base class:

```
public void MyMethod<T>(List<T> listOfBaseClass) where T : MyBaseClass {}
```

Now you can pass a list of subclasses.