# Why doesn't a reference variable of type A which contains reference to an object of type B can't access member functions of class B?

Tags: c#, class, object, inheritance, c#-4.0

Why can't objA access methodB() since it contains the reference to an object of class B type?

```
Class A 
{
     public void methodA()
     {
           .........
     }
}

Class B:A
{
     public void methodB()
     {
          ..........
     }
}
```

now

```
A obj1= new B();
```

this throws an error:

```
obj1.methodB();
```

why ? **obj1** contains the reference to an object of type **B** but still, it can't access member functions of it.

Comment: Let's say `ClassA` was `Fruit` and `ClassB` was `Apple`. `MethodA` is `EatFruit` and `MethodB` is `RemoveAppleCore`. Does it make sense to call `RemoveAppleCore` on **any** fruit (remember, it might be a strawberry or some other fruit)?

Comment: If you assign to a type `A` then the compiler doesn't know that it's a `B`. It could be just an `A` or even a `C`!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662369/covariance-and-contravariance-real-world-example might read that. As a complete answer on a question

Answer (score 2):

You declared the variable of type `A`:

```
A obj1
```

And `A` has no method called `methodB`.  If you want the *variable* to be of type `B`, declare it as such:

```
B obj1= new B();
```

(This would of course mean that you can't store any other implementations of `A` in that variable, only `B`.)

Or if you don't want to change the variable then you'd need to cast the variable:

```
(obj1 as B).methodB();
```

(This would of course fail if `obj1` ever contains an implementation of `A` that *isn't* a `B`.)

Basically, when you declare the variable of type `A`, the compiler maintains it as type `A`.  There is no guarantee at any point after declaration that the variable would contain an instance of `B`.  I could contain an instance of *anything* that implements `A`.

Answer (score 1):

When you put those two lines nicely together, you will think "of course i can execute `methodB()` on that object! It *is* a `B`, obviously!".

But now consider this:

```
private void DoSomethingWithAnA(A obj1)
{
    obj1.MethodB();
}
```

Why would this work? In this method, you only know that you receive an object `A`, nobody will assume that you have to call it with an object `B`. After all, if your method wanted to do something with a `B`, it should have asked for a `B`, not an `A`!

Of course, I can *call* the method with a `B`, this would not be a problem:

```
DoSomethingWithAnA(new B());
```

But that doesn't mean that `DoSomethingWithAnA` all of a sudden will do something with a `B`, it just does something with an `A`.

*If* you also want to do something B-specific, you can, however:

```
private void DoSomething(A obj1)
{
    obj1.MethodA();
    if (obj1 is B)
    {
        ((B)obj1).MethodB();
    }
}
```

This method *would* do something with a `B` if you pass it a `B`. However, it first needs to check if the `A` you send is actually also a `B`, and then it *casts* the `A` to a `B`. On the resulting `B` it can then call `MethodB()`.

Answer (score 0):

Because its called restrictive view from base class to derived. If you instantiate object using `polymorphism` like you do `obj1.methodB();` your `obj1` posses only things defined in parent class. This is possible because we know that derived class MUST have that definitions too (fields, properties, methods etc).

So that's why you cant call explicit `obj1.methodB();`but you can call `methodA()` with derived class implementation.

Examples:

```
A objA = new A();
objA.methodA(); //calling method implementation of class A
objA.methodB(); //compile time error  -> class A doesn't have that method

A objA = new B();
objA.methodA(); //calling method implementation of class B
objA.methodB(); //compile time error  -> during restrictive view trough parent class

B objB = new B();
objB.methodA(); //calling method implementation of class B
objB.methodB(); //calling method implementation of class B
```

Imagine that you have class C,D and so on, if you instantiate them with restrictive view you can call common method (defined in parent class) for all of them (children).

Example

```
List<A> list = new List() {objB,objC,objD};
foreach(A obj in list){
       obj.MethodA();
}
```