# Resolve compiler error in type constraint of generic type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics

I have a cascade of three abstract generic classes, as follows:

```
 public abstract class SpawnTrigger<T> 
 public abstract class SpawnerConfig <T, S> where T : SpawnTrigger<S> {}
 public abstract class Spawner<T, S> where T:SpawnerConfig<SpawnTrigger<S>, S>{}
```

I have three corresponding concrete classes.  Each one inherits from one of the abstract generic classes, as follows:

```
public class OrbSpawnTrigger : SpawnTrigger<Orb>{}
public class OrbSpawnerConfig : SpawnerConfig<OrbSpawnTrigger, Orb>{}
public class OrbSpawner : Spawner<OrbSpawnerConfig, Orb>{}
```

For simplicity I have removed the bodies of these classes, above.

The compiler is complaining about `OrbSpawner`.  Specifically, it is complaining that:

```
The type 'OrbSpawnerConfig' must be convertible to 'SpawnerConfig<SpawnTrigger<Orb>,Orb>' in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic class 'Spawner<T,S>'
```

I cannot figure out why it is complaining.  `OrbSpawnerConfig` is a `SpawnerConfig<SpawnTrigger<Orb>, Orb>`:

`OrbSpawnerConfig` -> `SpawnerConfig<OrbSpawnTrigger, Orb>` -> `SpawnerConfig<SpawnTrigger<Orb>, Orb>`

Does anyone understand this error?  I am working in C# on a Unity project.  Is there a peculiarity or limitation of C# that I am unaware of?

I should mention that the following produces no error - but it is not a solution because I want to specify a concrete class not the inherited generic abstract:

```
public class OrbSpawner : Spawner<SpawnerConfig<SpawnTrigger<Orb>, Orb>, Orb>
```

The error is easily reproducible with the following code:

```
namespace Test
{
    public abstract class SpawnTrigger<T> {}
    public abstract class SpawnerConfig<T, S> where T : SpawnTrigger<S> {}
    public abstract class Spawner<T, S> where T : SpawnerConfig<SpawnTrigger<S>, S>  {}

    public class OrbSpawnTrigger : SpawnTrigger<Orb> { }
    public class OrbSpawnerConfig : SpawnerConfig<OrbSpawnTrigger, Orb> { }
    public class OrbSpawner : Spawner<OrbSpawnerConfig, Orb> {}
}
```

Here is the same code refactored to use simple class names (the error is in the definition of ConcreteC - that ConcreteB cannot be used as parameter V)

```
namespace Test
{
    public abstract class A<T> {}
    public abstract class B<T, U>  where U : A<T> {}
    public abstract class C<T, V>  where V : B<T, A<T>> {}

    public class ConcreteA : A<MyObj> {}
    public class ConcreteB : B<MyObj, ConcreteA> {}
    public class ConcreteC : C<MyObj, ConcreteB> {}

    public class MyObj {}
}
```

Thanks to Dmitry Dovgopoly for providing a code solution that works, and to PetSerAI for explaining why my code has problems.  As I understand it, I cannot use a derived ConcreteB to satisfy the constraint of the more general requirements of parameter V. And the solution is to use Interfaces with the out keyword, to create a Covariant interface.  See [covariant generic interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier)

Comment: Variance does not work for classes. That means `SpawnerConfig<A, Orb>` -> `SpawnerConfig<B, Orb>` only true when `A` equals `B`, but not when `A` inherit from `B`.

Comment: https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4OwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABAFVgFwLACgDeeKxKAAgMwpgBGMmATkpmQEwoCCAPGgHwr4BfIiQpVaDJqxQAhbgBoUAVT4oA7gAso9VIpQAuDtz6DhxUTTqNEzUmwDC8lADUFy4hq2on+mY7cftJR8uXn4hXFMySlsUOwB7EERtTCh2YM4AWQBPAHlqACtjcJIoqXjE5KhpH1lsvPyFcqSoFPYiyNEYpsq7Hwc6gsaE5pTpIYqW1PaI3BLOtgH8sLwBIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your parameters can be covariant, you will fix this by adding interfaces

```
public interface ISpawnTrigger<out T>{}
public interface ISpawnerConfig<out T, S> where T : ISpawnTrigger<S>{}
public interface ISpawner<out T, S> where T : ISpawnerConfig<ISpawnTrigger<S>, S>{}
public abstract class SpawnTrigger<T> : ISpawnTrigger<T>{}
public abstract class SpawnerConfig<T, S> : ISpawnerConfig<T, S> where T : ISpawnTrigger<S>{}
public abstract class Spawner<T, S> : ISpawner<T, S> where T : ISpawnerConfig<ISpawnTrigger<S>, S>{}
public class OrbSpawnTrigger : SpawnTrigger<Orb>{}
public class OrbSpawnerConfig : SpawnerConfig<OrbSpawnTrigger, Orb>{}
public class OrbSpawner : Spawner<OrbSpawnerConfig, Orb>{}
public class Orb{}
```

[Covariance and contravariance real world example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662369/covariance-and-contravariance-real-world-example)

Comment: Thanks Dmitry.  I will study your answer to see if it is a complete solution for me.  I appreciate the link to the Covariance article.