# Cannot pass a non-nullable object as a parameter that accepts nullalble

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I have this simple code and it generates a warning:

```
private void MyMethod()
{
    IDictionary<string, object> notNullable = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    Test(notNullable);
}

private void Test(IDictionary<string, object?> nullable)
{
}
```

I get this warning when I try to compile (it does work with ! though):

> Argument of type 'Dictionary< string, object>' cannot be used for
>   parameter 'nullable' of type 'IDictionary' in '...'
>   due to differences in the nullability of reference types

Now I can see the problem doing it the other way around, but how is it a problem that I send a not nullable to a nullable parameter? Just a limitation of C# compiler, or perhaps a bug?

Comment: Isn't this an issue more with covariance/contravariance?

Comment: Its not a bug. U can cast non nullable to nullable and then pass.

Comment: You're trying to pass a `Dictionary<string, object>` to a method that takes an `IDictionary<string, Nullable<object>>`... why would that ever be allowed?

Comment: @Powerlord in C# 8.0, `Object?` is not the same thing as `Nullable<Object>`.

Comment: Yes, behind the scenes there is no difference at all. Nullable reference types are not the same as nullable value types

Comment: If you pass a non-nullable type to a function expecting a nullable type, and that function sets the value to null as part of its operation, what do you think should happen? Best case scenario when allowing non-nullable types to be passed in in place of a nullable type and you attempt to set it to null you'd see a runtime exception. But if you already know that this would throw such an exception in advance, like the compiler does, then why not throw an error on the attempt and not at runtime? Compiler errors are much more desirable than runtime errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the same problem as generic-type argument [covariance/contravariance problem](http://tomasp.net/blog/variance-explained.aspx/) because `IDictionary` supports "[in and out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)" movement of data (compared to `IReadOnlyDictionary` which is an "out" container).

The reason it <del>doesn't compile</del> gives a warning is because it would allow this:

```
// This code requires a C# 8.0 compiler!

private void MyMethod()
{
    IDictionary<String,Object> cannotContainNulls = new Dictionary<String,Object>();

    Test( cannotContainNulls );

    assert( cannotContainNulls[ "this has a null value" ] == null ); // this shouldn't be possible!
}

private void Test( IDictionary<String,Object?> canContainNulls )
{
    canContainNulls.Add( key: "this has a null value", value: null );
}
```

If you change your `Test` method to accept an `IReadOnlyDictionary` (where `TValue` is marked as `out` for contravariance (or covariance, I forget which is which) it should work.

Note that only interfaces and delegates can have their generic type parameters annotated with `in` and `out`, whereas concrete types (including abstract classes) cannot. This isn't a problem provided that programs that consume generic types expecting type argument variance are programmed to work with the interfaces instead of concrete types.

Comment: Although you are right about `IDictionary` being invariant in its types, AFAIK the types of `object` and `object?` are identical, since `object?` is synctactic sugar for the benefit of the compiler, not a different type (they are both still just `object`):

            object foo = new object();
            object? bar = new object();
            Debug.Assert(foo.GetType() == bar.GetType());

(and as per the OP, it does compile, and run, he just gets a warning)

Comment: @StuartLC, seems that the reason for the warning is the same as for covariance stuff. It will fully work of course, it's not even a syntactic sugar, it's just a warning generator really, but the warning is correctly generated since it can get into troubles later (no guarantee it won't be null)

Comment: Though you could fix "don't compile" to "gives a warning", perhaps that's wha @StuartLC meant :)

Comment: I'm fairly familiar with [covariance *stuff* :)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42660356/314291), but it's a bit sad to see that Code Contracts have died - the static checking was amazing, and not just for nulls. TBH I rather prefer the way that Scala / Java handle 'missing' data through use of the Option type / monad.

Comment: @StuartLC You're making me depressed :( (Code-contracts were amazing, but hard to sell  to people unfamiliar with the underlying concepts - and a "problem" with CC-heavy code is you end up using C# to write functional code and then you end-up asking yourself why you weren't using F# in the first place.

Comment: @StuartLC I'm in love with things like [`OneOf<T>`](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf) but they're still so cumbersome to use in C# - for example: having to use lambdas for each branch to abuse scopes for safety instead of a more succint syntax with no runtime overhead, or how we don't have a reasonable way to implement exhaustive `switch` , and so on. I was hoping that Roslyn's pluggable design would mean projects could introduce new syntax but so far all we have a new analyzers (which are nice, but have a long way to go).

Answer (score -1):

Until C# 7.0 you don't need this `object?` because the type object accept nullable values, same as strings. If it was for example a `int` then you need to do that `IDictionary<string, int?>`

Comment: What you're describing is only true up until C# 7.0. Since C# 8.0 all Object references are non-nullable by default.

Comment: @Dai Ok, thanks for the information, i did not know this!