# functioning of covariant in flutter

Tags: flutter, class, dart

I was going through dart documentation and there I came across this code and this term
`covariant`. I went through some documentation but I didn't get what is its `function` there. A detailed explained answer is always appreciated.

```
class Animal {
  void chase(Animal x) { ... }
}

class Mouse extends Animal { ... }

class Cat extends Animal {
  @override
  void chase(covariant Mouse x) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just try to remove the key word covariant and it will become self explanatory.

You will receive a compiler error that you are overiding a method with mismatch parameter type `Expected: Animal, Actual: Mouse`

However, Mouse is a subtype of Animal, so if you want to allow this case without error, add the covariant keyword

**Before**
[image]

**After**

[image]

Here you can see the Mouse is subtype of animal

Answer (score 59):

In Dart, if you override a superclass method, the arguments of the override method must have the
same type as the original.

Since `Animal.chase` in your example accepts an argument of `Animal`, you must do the same in your override:

```dart
class Cat extends Animal {
  @override
  void chase(Animal x) { ... }
}
```

Why? Imagine if there was no such restriction. `Cat` could define `void chase(Mouse x)` while `Dog` could
define `void chase(Cat x)`. Then imagine you have a `List<Animal> animals` and you call `chase(cat)` on
one of them. If the animal is a dog, it'll work, but if the animal is cat, Cat is not a Mouse! The Cat
class has no way to handle being asked to chase another Cat.

So you're forced to use `void chase(Animal x)`. We can simulate a `void chase(Mouse x)` type signature
by adding a runtime type check:

```dart
void chase(Animal x) {
  if (x is Mouse) {
    /* do chase */
  } else {
    /* throw error */
  }
}
```

It turns out this is a fairly common operation, and it would be nicer if it could be checked at compile time
where possible. So Dart added a `covariant` operator. Changing the function signature to `chase(covariant Mouse x)`
(where Mouse is a subclass of Animal) does three things:

1. Allows you to omit the `x is Mouse` check, as it is done for you.
2. Creates a compile time error if any Dart code calls `Cat.chase(x)` where x is not a Mouse or its subclass — if known at compile time.
3. Creates a runtime error in other cases.

---

Another example is the `operator ==(Object x)` method on objects. Say you have a class `Point`:

You could implement `operator==` this way:

```dart
class Point {
  final int x, y;
  Point(this.x, this.y);

  bool operator==(Object other) {
    if (other is Point) {
      return x == other.x && y == other.y;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

But this code compiles even if you compare `Point(1,2) == "string"` or a number or some other object. It makes no sense to compare a Point with things that aren't Points.

You can use `covariant` to tell Dart that `other` should be a Point, otherwise it's an error. This lets you drop the `other is Point` part, too:

```dart
bool operator==(covariant Point other) =>
  x == other.x && y == other.y;
```

---

**Why is it called 'covariant'?**

Covariant is a fancy type theory term, but it basically means 'this class or its subclasses'. Put another way, it means types
that are equal or lower in the type hierarchy.

You are explicitly telling Dart to tighten the type checking of this argument to a *subclass* of the original.
For the first example: tightening Animal to Mouse; for the second: tightening Object to Point.

Useful related terms are **contravariant**, which means types equal or higher in the type hierarchy, and **invariant**,
which means exactly this type.

For more information, [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662369/covariance-and-contravariance-real-world-example) is a good resource.

Comment: "Cat class has no way to handle being asked to chase another Cat" I see cats chasing cats all the time :))

Comment: I like the `covariant` operator means this class or its subclasses

Comment: It is similar to `<out T>` in kotlin and `<? extends T>` in java where T is maximum allowed upper bound in class hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

By using the covariant keyword, you disable the type-check and take responsibility for ensuring that you do not violate the contract in practice.

As you can see in the example, if you are overriding a method, its params should also be the same. But if you are using covariant, it will allow you to use Mouse instead of Animal.

Comment: No, technically,  you don't disable type checking, you are telling dart that this parameter can be Mouse, disabling type check means allowing any parameter like an Boolean or String or Num

Comment: The type checking is still done, too - at compile time if possible, otherwise at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Covariant is a keyword that allows you to override a method with a new type of parameter that is a subclass of the original type. This is handy when you want more precise behavior for different sorts of arguments without breaking compatibility with the superclass function.

```dart
class A {}

class B extends A {
}

class C extends B {
}

class D extends A {}
```

These are some simple classes that I will use to demonstrate different types of parameters.

```dart
// Create a class with a method
class P {
  void method(B b) {}
}

// You can create another class and override the 
// method without changing the type of the parameter.
class Q extends P {
  @override
  void method(B b) {}
}

// Without any problem, you can override 
// the method to take a superclass as an argument.
class R extends P {
  @override
  void method(A a) {}
}

// But if you override to take a subclass
// it gives an error.
class S extends P {
  @override
  void method(C c) {}  // Error
}

// You can avoid this error by 
// adding the `covariant` keyword.
class T extends P {
  @override
  void method(covariant C c) {}
}

// You can even add `covariant` with
// a superclass of the original type.
class U extends P {
  @override
  void method(covariant A a) {}
}

// But you can't use this to override
// methods to take arguments with unrelated types. 
// (Not in the hierarchy of the original type)
class V extends P {
  @override
  void method(covariant D d) {}  // Error
}
```