# C# generic inheritance, base class casting

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I wanted to make the following inheritance with included generics, but the final cast
`a as A<XBase>` always results in null, because the cast is not valid. Could anybody elaborate on why this cast would be invalid, as well as maybe a solution to this problem.

```
public class XBase {}
public interface A<T> where T : XBase 
{
    //Edited
    void Method(T param);
}


public class Implementor : A<Implementor.ImplementorX > 
{
    public class ImplementorX : XBase {public int a;}

    //Edited
    void Method(ImplementorX param) {}
}

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new Implementor();
        
        var castRes = a as A<XBase>;
        Console.WriteLine(castRes != null);
    }
}
```

see live example https://rextester.com/BTNVT61833

EDITED: Added a method to `interface A<T>` bc else it could be solved with @DavidG's response

Comment: You should go learn about covariance/contravariance. You could make this work by changing your interface: `public interface A<out T> where T : XBase `

Comment: oh great, but what if I had a method that takes T as a parameter in A<T>?

Comment: Your code no longer compiles. You need to implement `Method` in `Implementor`.

Comment: When you implement `Method`, you will see it takes an `ImplementorX` parameter. An `XBase` is not an `ImplementorX` so you can't do the cast. Try changing the interface method to be `Method(XBase param)` and then you can use `out` and it will work.

Comment: The main point of this T in Method was to assure that there could be objects of type ImplementorX be passed inside Implementor. I wanted to have it that way to not be required to perform casting in the Method of the corresponding implementors. Although it seems like this is not possible.

Comment: Let's say I have two types, `Apple` and `Banana`; both of which implement `IFruit`. Now I create a `BowlOf<Apple>` collection. If I were able to cast this to `BowlOf<IFruit>` (which is what you're doing with the `a as A<XBase>`) then I would be able to add a `Banana` to my `BowlOf<Apple>` - and that's not right and that's why the cast isn't allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make an explicit cast:

```
var castRes = A<XBase>(a);
```

then you will see the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type '' to type '`

Why? In my view, it is better to understand using real world example. I've renamed classes [based on this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2662396/1646240). There are comments which maps explanations to your classes in question.

Abstractions:

```
// XBase 
public class Animal { }

// class ImplementorX : XBase {public int a;}
public class Bird : Animal
{
    public string WingColor { get; set; }
}

// interface A<T> where T : XBase 
public interface IHat<T> where T : Animal
{
    void Hide(T param);

    T Pull();
}
```

Concrete implementations:

```
// class Implementor : A<Implementor.ImplementorX > 
public class Peacock : IHat<Bird>
{
    // void Method(ImplementorX param) {}
    void IHat<Bird>.Hide(Bird param)
    { }

    public Bird Pull()
    { }
}
```

and how it can be called:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Peacock peacockHat = new Peacock();

    IHat<Animal> animalHat = (IHat<Animal>) peacockHat; // runtime error 'Unable to cast
    // object of type 'HelloWorld.Peacock' to type 'HelloWorld.IHat`1

    // because 
    animalHat.Hide(new Dolphin()); // Hide a dolphin in a peacock hat?  
}
```

So we cannot `hide` hat of `Peacock` from `Dolphin`. It is not okay. CLR prevents us from making inappropriate actions.

**In short:**

In short, imagine you have two animals such as `Wolf` and `Sheep`. And these classes implements IAnimal interface:

```
public interface IAnimal
{    }

public class Wolf: IAnimal
{    }

public class Sheep : IAnimal
{    }
```

So `Sheep`, `Wolf` classes implement the inherited interface `IAnimal`:

```
            IAnimal
             /  \
            /    \
         Sheep   Wolf
```

And then these animals can be put in cage:

```
public class Cage<T> where T : IAnimal
{
    public void Put(T animal)
    {   }
}
```

Then you create a cage for `Sheep`. After that somebody wants to cast `Sheep` cage to `IAnimal`:

```
Cage<Sheep> sheepCage = new Cage<Sheep>();
sheepCage.Put(new Sheep());

Cage<IAnimal> animalCage = (Cage<Wolf>)sheepCage; // compile error
// if there were no error, then you will be able to do:
animalCage.Put(new Wolf()); // it is not good idea
```

Comment: That's a complicated example. I know where you're trying to get to in the explanation, but I can't see it.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks for the reply. I just wanted to map author's code to real example objects to show why it prevents from casting. I've updated my answer

Comment: That's a much better example! A little graphic, but I think that helps.

Comment: @Enigmativity yeah, I've added some simple scheme:)

Comment: Wow great explanation thanks a lot!

Comment: @P.Steininger I am glad that it helped to you :)