# Covariance and invariance of generics

Tags: types, covariance

Why is it a bad idea to allow programmers to specify the covariance and invariance of generics themselves? We could make the `Action<T>` class covariant, because if we can do an action on `T2 < T1`, then we can do it on `T1`, which means `Action<T1> < Action<T2>`. We could make an immutable `List<T2> < List<T1>` if `T2 < T1`

I saw something similar only in Kotlin, but there it was achieved by controlling mutability on the part of the compiler. I have never seen anything like this anywhere else

Comment: I am assuming you are talking about C# here?

Comment: @Mushroomator Not really, but if there are good examples on the topic in C#, they might answer my question. I'm not familiar with C#

Comment: In C# you can declare generic type arguments as covariant or contravariant. And you (obviously accidentally) manged to use a type which is contravariant i. e. `Action<in T>`, therefore my question. Maybe [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662369/covariance-and-contravariance-real-world-example) might help. It's for C# but should be fairly easy to understand for anyone familiar with OOP especially Java/ Kotlin.